# Motivation and Applications for Toric Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, toric-geometry

I'm a graduate student of mathematics starting to study algebraic geometry with a focus on toric varieties (along *Cox, Little, Schenck)*. From what I have learned so far, I can grasp that toric varieties form a subclass of algebraic varieties that can be studied using the combinatorics of polyhedral fans, where properties are easier to compute than in the general setting of algebraic varieties.

To this point, I have treated the subject rather abstractly and haven't seen any applications of the theory.

I would love to hear about some applications of toric geometry, to get a better understanding and probably some motivation. Where and why do toric varieties appear?

Comment: I am not an algebraic geometer, but here's what I think is true: They provide lots of examples that are easy to compute with, which is nice in such an abstract subject. They also have applications to physics, especially string theory and mirror symmetry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Potato said in the comments, toric varieties are extremely easy to compute with compared with a general variety. As soon as the defining equations are not binomial, most algorithms are extremely slow. But if the variety is defined by binomials (i.e. it is a toric variety), then we can use lots of combinatorial machinery to compute. For example, for primary decomposition, there's an algorithm by Eisenbud/Sturmfels that is extremely fast, and works with binomial ideals.

It is written a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521857007) about algebraic statistics, whose algorithms mainly assume the equations are toric.

It also appearantly has applications in mirror symmetry in physics, see [Martinez-Garcia *Toric varieties in a nutshell*](http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/martinezgarcia/papers/toricNutshell.pdf) for more details (page 32 and onwards). Basically, there's some duality going on because of the polytopes, some desingularization, and some deformation theory. I don't know the details, just the buzzwords.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I guess you meant to say "if the variety is defined by binomials"?

Comment: @ChristophPegel Yes, of course! Thank you for the comment.